# Subir base de datos oracle a un host

Tags: oracle

Os comento, tengo una base de datos oracle en una máquina virtual que está conectada a una página web.(Todo en localhost)

Quisiera saber si hay algún hosting(gratuito) donde pueda subir la base de datos oracle, o si habría alguna forma de subir la página web a un host y que se conectara a la base de datos de mi ordenador.

Tengo que presentar un proyecto,y me gustaría que mientras explico todo, pudieran ver la pagina web desde el movil/ordenador y pudieran testear todo.

¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: la mayoria de los hosting gratuitos solo soportan mysql como gestor de bases de datos, dudo que encuentres una opción así como gratuita para oracle

Comment: Coincido con Alfredo, lo que puedes hacer es lo que comentas hostear la pag y apuntas hacia tu máquina, puedes crear un dominio en no-ip.com para tu máquina de manera que no tengas que estar pendiente de la ip. saludos!